# Xcode and No paired Apple Watch

Tags: xcode, apple-watch

I've already seen a similar question that doesn't give a valid answer to me: [In Xcode I see (no paired Apple Watch) even though the watch is paired and the watch's UDID is registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792520/in-xcode-i-see-no-paired-apple-watch-even-though-the-watch-is-paired-and-the-w)

I really cannot understand how to have my Apple Watch working on Xcode. 
Even if I create a new project or if I add a watch target to an existing app I always see in the device choice this status "My iPhone (No paired Apple Watch)" but my Apple watch IS paired... 
Sometimes the message changes and I get "My iPhone (Paired device not available for development)". 
My current environment is fully updated to the latest software versions (Xcode, WatchOS, iOS and OS X).

Are there any magic solution to make it work?!

Comment: What level of Xcode do you have? Which leads to the question: what's the max OS version Xcode can compile to?  And what's the version on the Apple Watch?

Comment: @GlennRay My current environment is fully updated to the latest software versions (Xcode, WatchOS, iOS and OS X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just experienced this. It was caused because the ios app which contains the watch app was out of date on the phone. After switching target to the ios app and building and run it on my phone, I was then able to switch back to the watch app and successfully run it on my watch.

Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002). macOS 10.12.3 (16D32).

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I just ran into this problem. My phone and watch are both registered, etc. I checked my provisioning profiles on the developer portal and they happened to be invalid (I reset something along the way).

After fixing them, downloading, and double-clicking them, the watch appeared as paired again.

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode 10 beta, I experienced the (no paired Apple Watch) scenario
After a few moments, the "Do you trust this computer" dialogue came up on the watch. after accepting it, Xcode saw the watch right away

Comment: this just doesn't work

Comment: I swear nothing on internet helped me pair apple watches to xcode, iphone appears, trust this computer appears on watches, and watches just do not appear in xcode destinations