# Xcode does not install watchOS app for debugging on device

Tags: xcode, watchkit, watchos

This is on watchOS 4.3 beta (15T5165e) and Xcode 9.3 beta (9Q98q), but I don't think it's because of them being in beta because another WatchKit project ran on device just fine. I have tried unpairing/repairing, restarting the iPhone/Watch/macOS/Xcode (while making sure to to tap "trust this computer" on the watch) but Xcode still says "Running" in the WatchKit scheme without actually installing and running the watchOS app, eventually saying "Watch app launch timed out."

Comment: This is an issue that has been plaguing Xcode probably every since WatchKit first came out. I have *never* been able to reliably build and run on the actual watch. Even when Xcode said I had a paired iPhone and watch it usually fails like you describe, and then on top of that I've also had my share of pairing nightmares. I have found the best chance to successfully deploy on the watch is to 1) quit and restart Xcode and 2) have the watch app running on the phone.

Comment: @daver This still happens to me unfortunately. If you can still reproduce it, any chance you could file a report if you haven't already in Bug Reporter and include logs of Xcode, iPhone and its paired Apple Watch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Xcode I see (no paired Apple Watch) even though the watch is paired and the watch's UDID is registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792520/in-xcode-i-see-no-paired-apple-watch-even-though-the-watch-is-paired-and-the-w)

Comment: Try to make a hotspot with your iPhone...helped sometimes.

Comment: @Appyx, it helped me. Magic!

Comment: I tried what @Appyx suggested however it didn't work for me, it's so unfortunate that Apple is not even paying any attention to such a trivial issue, anyway what worked for me is just restarting my XCode, give it a try.

Comment: Currently on Xcode 15 and it seems to have been fixed.

Answer (score 10):

Disable WiFi on the iPhone. This helped me.

I came to this after following @Appyx advice to activate a hotspot on iPhone. Then I noticed, that in hotspot mode WiFi is automatically disabled and tried this.

Comment: This worked! I am using iPhone 10s Max with Apple Watch 5 (6.2 WatchOS) and had the issue of installing my app from XCode to Apple Watch. After I turned off the WiFi, it worked.

Comment: Combining the WiFi toggling with the clearing of the device support files mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792520/in-xcode-i-see-no-paired-apple-watch-even-though-the-watch-is-paired-and-the-w eventually worked for me. It took multiple goes. MacOS 11.1, XCode 12.3, iOS 14.2 and WatchOS 7.2