# Strange paired watch state in Xcode

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, watchos

I have a watch paired to my phone, but it shows up as Name: null, Model: Unknown in Xcode's Devices and Simulators.

The watch is not recognised as a valid target, but works as usual for everything else, including unlocking my laptop. So far I've tried, without success:

- Unpairing and re-pairing
- Removing the Xcode account and adding back
- Restarting the watch

Any ideas how to get this watch back for development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: Pairing the watch again as a new device (as opposed to restoring from backup) fixed this. The complete procedure is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47412942/415025